# Reuse views in NodeJS without calling Controller action

Tags: node.js, express

I have 2 actions in a controller, say I have a `Projects` "controller" and two actions : `.all` and `.my`.

- The `all` action will retrieve all `Project` records in the database
  and render a view to show them in a list.
- The `my` action will do the same, but will only show those projects
  that were created by the current user.

How do I reuse the `all` view in the my action, without having to duplicate the view for the `my` action? If I call this code in the `my` action:

```
        res.render('projects/all',
            projects : projects
        )
```

the `all` action in the controller is called, overriding my `projects` array. This was common in Rails, but in NodeJS I cannot figure out how to do it. Thanks.

EDIT:

Here is the code for my actions (i have given up meanwhile and have used two separate views `all` and `my` with the same HTML generation code:

```
exports.all = function(req, res) {
Project.all(req.db, function(err, projects) {

    var viewVars = {
        title: "All projects"
    };

    viewVars = req.db.paginate(req,
        viewVars
    );

    if(!err && projects != null)
    {
        viewVars.projects = projects;
        res.render('projects/all',
            viewVars
        )
    }
    else
    {
        viewVars.projects = [];
        viewVars.error_messages = ["No projects available"];
        res.render('projects/all',
            viewVars
        )
    }
});
};

exports.my = function(req, res) {
Project.findByCreator(req.db, req.session.user.uri, function(err, projects) {

    var viewVars = {
        //title: "My projects"
    };

    viewVars = req.db.paginate(req,
        viewVars
    );

    if(!err && projects != null)
    {
        viewVars.projects = projects;
        res.render('projects/my',
            viewVars
        )
    }
    else
    {
        viewVars.projects = [];
        viewVars.info_messages = ["You have not created any projects"];
        res.render('projects/my',
            viewVars
        );
    }
});
};
```

Comment: Can you please post some more code.

Comment: Done. Check the original answer please :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your route...

Something like

```
app.get("/projects/:option(all|my)", yourcontroller);
```

Then you can use

```
req.params.option
```

to tell determine which data to load, and send that data into your one new view.

Comment: Thanks, I will check this out and report on the findings.

Comment: Well, this is sort of a work around, but since no other solution has appeared I will accept this answer.